# Meteor - How to check if an image exists (server-side)

Tags: javascript, meteor

**My goal:** Show a default image if one does not exist.

**My approach:** I've created a helper that makes a server-side Meteor.call to check if the image url exists. The helper's intent is to either return a default image path (does not exist) or the dynamic path (image exists).

**Where I'm stuck**

1. Helper: On the client, I can successfully console.log the output
   from the server-side method (result.statusCode). However, the helper does not return my
   desired string in the template (/images/db/...etc).
2. Method: I'm getting a 200 results
   status for ALL file paths, even ones that don't exist. I suspect
   this has to do with iron-router's global NotFound template, but not
   sure how to get around it. I tried using fs.exists but could never
   get it to find a file (all responses were false).

Any and all suggestions most appreciated. If there's a simpler way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

---

**HTML:**

`<img src="{{imagePath key}}avatar.jpg">`

**My helper:**

```
UI.registerHelper('imagePath', function(key){

  //Build the Meteor.call url
  var $host = document.location.host;
  var $imgBaseUrl = '/images/db/'
  var $assetPath = $imgBaseUrl + key + '/';
  var url = 'http://' + $host + $assetPath + 'bg.jpg';

  //Define the default image location
  var $assetPathDefault = $imgBaseUrl + 'default' + '/';

  //Call the server-side method
  Meteor.call('checkIfImageExists', url, function(error, result) {

    if (false) {
      console.log('Error');
      return $assetPathDefault;
    } else {
      console.log('Result: ' + result.statusCode);
      console.log($assetPath);
      return $assetPath;
    };
  });
});
```

**Server-side method**

```
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
  checkIfImageExists: function(url) {
    check(url, String);
    var fut = new Future();
    this.unblock();
    HTTP.get(url, function (error, result) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log('Found a file!: ' + url);
        console.log('Result: ' + result.statusCode);
        fut.return (result);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
        fut.return (false);
      };
    });
    return fut.wait();
  }
});
```

---

FWIW - I'm adding the "url check" to an old helper that simply inserted a string w/out checking if the image existed. Worked great.

```
UI.registerHelper('imagePath', function(key){
  var baseUrl = '/images/db/';
  return baseUrl + key + '/';
});
```

Comment: Using a Future to make HTTP.get synchronous is reinventing the wheel, check the docs there is already a synchronous version :)

Comment: "I'm getting a 200 results status for ALL file paths, even ones that don't exist." => this is probably because of the if(false) statement in your method call return callback !

Comment: Appreciate the comments saimeunt...I'll plop the sync call back in and see if I can get it to work. Re: 200 results, if I switch the url to a path I know does not exist (e.g. on an outside site) it does indeed provide the 404. If you have any opinions on HTTP vs fs.exists vs some other solution that's iron-router friendly I'm still stuck there. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your client–side  helper doesn't return anything! Check out the structure you've used:

```
function a() {
  ...
  Meteor.call(..., function b() {
    return something;
  });
}
```

The `return something` is a return statement of function `b`, while function `a` has no return statement – thus it returns undefined.

Meteor server-side methods are (and have to be) asynchrounous, while the nature of client-side Javascript implies that the helper methods are synchronous (there is no "wait" in the browser). Thus, to use a server-side method inside a client-side helper you have to take advantage of reactivity. Fortunately, it's pretty easy with a `ReactiveDict`:

```
var imagePathDict = new ReactiveDict();

UI.registerHelper('imagePath', function(key) {
   ...
   if(!imagePathDict.get(key)) {
     // the path was not initialized, fetch it from the server
     Meteor.call(..., function(error, result) {
       ...
       imagePathDict.set(key, result.assetPath);
     });
   }
   // return the reactive path
   return imagePathDict.get(key);
});
```

---

By the way, don't start your variable names with `$` (unless you refer to a jQuery object), it's against conventions in Javascript.

Comment: One note: last time I checked `ReactiveDict` wasn't a part of meteor-platform, so make sure to add `reactive-dict` to your `.meteor/packages` file.

Comment: This is very valuable Hubert, thank you...you just taught a man to fish.